# CURL - Problem with Authentication

Tags: php, curl

I need to add authentication to this function:

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);

  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

I'm looking to add authentication to this function, something along these lines?

```
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the code you posted? That looks good to me:

```
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

But **this function already works with auth**, just pass the auth string `"user:pass"` in the `$options` array.

```
multiRequest($data, array('CURLOPT_USERPWD' => "user:pass"));
```

If you're looking to set auth for each curl handle, something like this should work:

```
// auth?
if (is_array($d)) {
  if (!empty($d['user']) AND !empty($d['pass']) {
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$d['user']}:{$d['pass']}");
  }
}
```

Then just pass `'user'` and `'auth'` elements as part of the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Can the function definition be changed?

```
function multiRequest($data,$user,$pwd, $options = array())
```

Then in the `foreach` loop, do the following:

```
...
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pwd");

// post?
...
```